# mock.assert_called_with returns inconsistent results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have the below code running in 2 different branches which returns different outputs.

```
@patch("src.core.Preferences.get_preferences")
def test_get_preferences(self, mock):
    pref_service = Preferences()
    pref_service.get_preferences()
    mock.assert_called_with("foo", ScopeType.FOO, "bar")
```

This test is failing in one branch and passing in another one. I debugged the code and went to the `__eq__` method to understand how these are different. Failing at this check in mock https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4662fa9bfe4a849fe87bfb321d8ef0956c89a772/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2489

When printed values for these checks in below order, found that these are working in different way

```
print((other_args, other_kwargs) == (self_args, self_kwargs))
print((other_args, other_kwargs))
print((self_args, self_kwargs))
```

#### Failing test returns this value

```
False
(('foo', <ScopeType.FOO: 'foo'>, 'bar'), {})
(('foo', <ScopeType.FOO: 'foo'>, 'bar'), {})
```

#### Passing test

```
True
(('foo', <ScopeType.FOO: 'foo'>, 'bar'), {})
(('foo', <ScopeType.FOO: 'foo'>, 'bar'), {})
```

Can someone help me understand this behaviour ?

Comment: What does the` __eq__` function for ScopeType.FOO look like?

Comment: `ScopeType` is an Enum